# I get android runtime error when applying multiple if conditions, android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi I have following code which is used to calculate get the subnet mask input from editText and I am performing multiple conditions on a single if line. Basically i have broken the 4 parts of the subnet using .split and saved then in arrays. Here is the code anyway.

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String strings = String.valueOf(inputIp.getText().toString());
            final String parts[] = strings.split("\\.");
                   String block1 = parts[0];
                   String block2 = parts[1];
                   String block3 = parts[2];
                   String block4 = parts[3];

                   Double firstblock = Double.parseDouble(block1);
                   Double secondblock = Double.parseDouble(block2);
                   Double thirdblock = Double.parseDouble(block3);
                   Double fourthblock = Double.parseDouble(block4);

                   String substring = String.valueOf(inputSubnet.getText().toString());
                    String subPart[] = substring.split("\\.");
                        String  subBlock1 = subPart[0];
                        String  subBlock2 = subPart[1];
                        String  subBlock3 = subPart[2];
                        String  subBlock4 = subPart[3];

                        Double firstSubBlock =  Double.parseDouble(subBlock1);
                        Double secondSubBlock = Double.parseDouble(subBlock2);
                        Double thirdSubBlock = Double.parseDouble(subBlock3);
                        Double fourthSubBlock = Double.parseDouble(subBlock4);

            if(firstblock <= 127){

        //problem       
if((firstSubBlock == 255 || firstSubBlock !=0) &&  (secondSubBlock ==0 && secondSubBlock !=null) &&(thirdSubBlock== 0 && thirdSubBlock !=null) &&(fourthSubBlock == 0 && fourthSubBlock !=null)){
                int rangedisplay = (int) (Math.pow(2, 24)-2);
                showClass.setText("A");
                rangeDisplay.setText(rangedisplay);

                }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid subnet mask !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }else if(firstblock <=191){

                if((firstSubBlock == 255) && (secondSubBlock==255) &&(thirdSubBlock== null) &&(fourthSubBlock == null)){
                int rangedisplay = (int) (Math.pow(2, 16)-2);
                showClass.setText("B");
                rangeDisplay.setText(rangedisplay);
                }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid subnet mask !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }else if(firstblock <=223){

                if((firstSubBlock == 255) && (secondSubBlock==255) &&(thirdSubBlock==255) &&(fourthSubBlock == null)){
                    int rangedisplay = (int) (Math.pow(2, 8)-2);
                    showClass.setText("C");
                    rangeDisplay.setText(rangedisplay);

                   }else
                    {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid subnet mask !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a valid Ip Address !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }





        }
```

On the line below I commented "problem" I am passing multiple conditions and even though I enter the exact true conditions. I get runtime error or a toast message saying "Enter a valid Subnet mask!!" which is not right as I have entered all the conditions true which should execute the if block. Thank you so much for your time. Any suggestion would be appreciated as this is my University assignment and I am nearing the deadline. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the int variable random display is not parsed into a String. That was the problem, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using int's instead of Double. Comparing double's directly with == is not the right way to do it in Java.